# Wordpress Custom Post Type Query and Rewrite Rules

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type with custom fields which need to be filtered by URL query vars. Following this tutorial, everything works fine so far: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-wp-archive-custom-field-filter/

The URL /coins/?material=1&country=AF&year=&filter=country returns a filtered result in the view. But as soon as I start using a rewritten URL - f.e. /coins/material/1/country/AF/ the URL jumps back to /coins/ although the content of $meta_query is the same in both ways.

Note: As $_GET on a rewritten URL does not work, I changed to $wp_query->query_vars

in functions.php I have the following pre-filter (shortened code) and the rewrite rules:

```
$GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] = array(
'field_1'   => 'material',
'field_2'   => 'country'
);

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');
    global $wp_query;

    foreach( $GLOBALS['my_query_filters'] as $key => $name ) {
        $value = explode(',', $wp_query->query_vars[ $name ]);
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => $name,
            'value'     => $value,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        );
    }

    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

}

function custom_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%material%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%country%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);

function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^coins/material/([^/]*)/country/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=1024&material=$matches[1]&country=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

Any ideas? As mentioned, it works perfectly without the URL rewriting. Using nice URL's, I get the correct query vars but as soon as it gets to the line $query->set... the URL jumps to the domain/custom-post-type. Many thanks for your hints :-)